# jQuery custom plugin - how properly return results?

Tags: jquery, object, plugins, null, undefined

I'm creating my first jQuery plugin to easy get needed data without repeating the same scripts for different elements. I'd like to my plugin could get things like: width, height, position and more of specified element and his parent (I'll need them to use later) in forms like:

```
$('element').myPlugin(); // will return all
$('element').myPlugin(width); // will return only width
$('element').myPlugin(width, height); // will return width and height
```

I don't know the way how to get data from plugin in proper form. I tried to figure it out but always get "undefined" or [Object object] as result. I'll be grateful if someone could give me example how my "[[?]]" part should look:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {

        var defaults = {
            width: this.width(),
            height: this.height(),
            parentWidth: this.parent().width(),
            [[more]]
        }
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    return this.each(function () {

    var $this = $(this);

    [[?]]

    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: do you need a plugin? would a function or a variable be easier?

Comment: I believe plugin will be the best way, because it would be very handy to use it in my project. Plugin will calculate for ex. right and bottom position of element (jQuery haven't builded it in). Variables are easier - that's true, but my actual code is full of them already and is damn messy, so I'd like to re-create it.

Answer (score 0):

one way to do this is to store the data into the element 'data object'. here is the code:

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {
    var defaults = {
        width: this.width(),
        height: this.height(),
        parentWidth: this.parent().width(),
        [[more]]
    }
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    return this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var dimen = {width: width, height: height, ..}

        $this.data('dimen', diemn);
    };
};
```

Now apply your plugin:

```
 $('selector').myPlaugin();
```

Later you can get the data:

```
 $('selector').data('dimen'); //will return the dimention object
```

There may be better ways to do this.

Comment: It was returning "undefined" but I changed part "var dimen = {width: width, ...}" to "var dimen = {width: defaults.width, ...} and it works. However I'm still looking for other solutions to could use the plugin in form like: $('element').myPlugin(width);